# Required SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, null, mariadb

Table 1

```
 **asset_tag         assigned_to     serial              model_number**            
 AST-L1516-0127             NULL     NDD513738D          HP 240                  
 AST-D1112-0205                1     ddafadf             HP 240                  
 AST-D1213-0202             NULL     L52ha13             Lenovo thinkcenter M72e 
 AST-D1516-0203                2     FGBH622             Dell Optiplex 3020      
 AST-L1516-0077             NULL     3835LY32            Dell LATITUDE 3450      
 AST-L1415-0002             NULL     CNFGH95LZJ          HP 240G3
```

And Table 2

```
id   username 
1     pavan
2     kalyan
```

Required command to get below table based on above two tables,
assigned_to in table1 = id in table2 if assigned is not available in table 2 then it should add not available

```
 **asset_tag         assigned_to     serial              model_number                username** 
 AST-L1516-0127             NULL     NDD513738D          HP 240                     Not Available
 AST-D1112-0205                1     ddafadf             HP 240                     pavan
 AST-D1213-0202             NULL     L52ha13             Lenovo thinkcenter M72e    Not Available
 AST-D1516-0203                2     FGBH622             Dell Optiplex 3020         kalyan
 AST-L1516-0077             NULL     3835LY32            Dell LATITUDE 3450         Not Available
 AST-L1415-0002             NULL     CNFGH95LZJ          HP 240G3                   Not Available
```

Comment: Learn about `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL()`.

Comment: hi tried this command but not working SELECT a.asset_tag,a.assigned_to,a.serial,u.username FROM table1 a,table2 u LEFT JOIN username ON a.assigned_to=u.id;

Comment: "not working" = "syntax error"?  "crash"?  "too much output"?  "too little output"?  something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use coalesce() function

```
select a.asset_tag, a.assigned_to,a.serial,a.model_number,coalesce(b.username,'Not Available') as username
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.assigned_to = b.id;
```